# Can't use Adobe flash player - local storage

Tags: firefox, flash

Whenever i try to accept Adobe to store information om my computer it does absolutely nothing. This is what it say's:

```
Adobe Flash PLayer Settings
Local Storage
s.ytimg.com is requesting permission to store information on your computer.

Requested: up to 10 KB
Currently Used: 0 KB

Allow | Deny
```

Can I set it to Allow as default in Firefox's settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a more direct method, but I use this site to manage flash settings

http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

use the "Global AStorage Settings" tab

[image: Storage settings]